# How to translate label "Week x"?

Tags: highcharts, translation, gantt-chart

I have a problem with translate the label of `Axis-x` on `HighCharts Gantt`.

At this moment this is display like `Week 39` but I want to change by `Semana 39`. How can I?

Simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/bk3d4vfm/

Comment: Hi Beatriz and welcome on board of stack overflow. It would be helpful if you update your question to show a minimal example. This includes some (dummy) data to create the plot up to the point where you need help. This will help us to answer your questions faster. Have a look at our "How to ask questions" Guideline here on SO.

Comment: Hi MichaelA, thank you for you help. I just addded a little example and then i will look at the guide :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `week` in `dateTimeLabelFormats`:

```
xAxis: {
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        week: {
            list: ['Semana %W', 'W%W']
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/02wgbvx7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.week